# if inside if .. if in functional scope

Tags: javascript, json

I`m trying to parse a parsed xml2js response to json response in backend.

```
  if (resp['soapenv:Envelope'] && resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'] &&
        resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0] &&
        resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['p5:sevResp'] &&
        resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['p5:sevResp'][0]) {
        var result =
        resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['p5:sevResp'][0];
        if (result.sevReturn &&
            result.sevReturn[0]) {
            var sev =
                result['sevReturn'][0]['Sev'];
            if (sev) {// Build json}
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please read [ask]. In particular, the title should state the purpose of the code (something about SOAP to JSON) rather than your concern about the code. You should also include a sample of the SOAP response. Finally, please ensure that the code actually works, and is not just a stub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good formatting helps a lot:

```
if (resp['soapenv:Envelope'] &&
    resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'] &&
    resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0] &&
    resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['p5:sevResp'] &&
    resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['p5:sevResp'][0] &&
    resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['p5:sevResp'][0]['sevReturn'] &&
    resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['p5:sevResp'][0]['sevReturn'][0]) {

  var sev = resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['p5:sevResp'][0]['sevReturn'][0]['sev'];

  if (sev) {
    // TODO: built json
  }
}
```

To get rid of repeated property access, you could use [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4034468/1647737):

```
var sev = (((((((resp || {})['soapenv:Envelope'] || {})['soapenv:Body'] || [])[0] || {})['p5:sevResp'] || [])[0] || {})['sevReturn'] || [])[0];

if (sev) {
  // TODO: built json
}
```

Or, if your response would only exceptionally miss any of these properties, [handle the occasional exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631168/1647737):

```
try {
  var sev = resp['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][0]['p5:sevResp'][0]['sevReturn'][0]['Sev'];

  if (sev) {
    // TODO: built json
  }
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    // TODO: handle missing properties
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Also check the [other answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key/4034468#4034468) and use a library function if available such as [lodash's `_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get).

Answer (score 3):

If the nested ifs are a concern, you can use early returns for validity checks if this whole process is happening in a function context. You can also assign nested objects into temporary variables to prevent multiple lookups as you did for sev and result.

```
var envelope = resp['soapenv:Envelope'];
if (!envelope)
{
  return;
}
var body = envelope['soapenv:Body'];
if (!body || !body[0])
{
  return;
}
var sevResp = body[0]['p5:sevResp'];
if (!sevResp || !sevResp[0])
{
  return;
}
var sevReturn = sevResp[0].sevReturn;
if (!sevReturn || !sevReturn[0])
{
  return;
}
var sev = sevReturn[0]['Sev'];
if (!sev)
{
  return;
}
// TODO: build json
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the conditional even checking for? If the fields are set? My first step of making it more readable would be to replace the nasty conditionals with calls to methods.

```
if (this.responseIsValid(resp)) 
{
    if (this.resultShouldBeProcessed(this.getResult(resp))) 
    {
        if (this.getSev(result)) 
        {
              return this.buldJson(result);
        }
    }
}
```